# C++ Syntax error when declaring function inside function

Tags: c++, function

I am trying to create a program that allows me to find the nth root of a number. I tried running this on xcode and, I get an error that prevents me from running it. I'm getting an error for this line:

```
double f(double x) {
```

In this line, I am trying to declare a function, but it seems I'm declaring it incorrectly. xcode says `expected ;`. How can I address this issue?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cctype>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "helloworld.h"
#include <locale>

using namespace std;
double newton( int n, int number);
string lowercase (string word);

int main()
{
    int n;
    int number;
    cout << "This program can find the nth root of a number without actually solving the problem" <<endl;
    cout << "Tell me what the value of n is: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "What is the number that you want to get rooted";
    cin >> number;

    newton(n, number); 
}

double newton( int n, int number) {
    const double epsilon = .0001;
    double x0;
    double x1 = number;

    double f(double x) {
        return (double) pow(x, n) - number;
    }
    double der_f(double x) {
        return (double) n*pow(x, n-1);
    }

    while( abs(x1-x0) < epsilon) {
        x0 = x1;
        x1 = x0 -f(x0)/der_f(x0); 
    }
    return x1;
}
```

Comment: That function is defined within another.

Comment: So why didn't you post that code?

Comment: Related post with various useful suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324763/c-can-we-have-functions-inside-functions

Answer (score 2):

If you really want function inside function - there is a hack.
You could define struct with static function inside your function.

Example:

```
double newton( int n, int number) {
    const double epsilon = .0001;
    double x0;
    double x1 = number;

    struct wrap {
       static int n;
       static double f(double x) {
           return (double) pow(x, n) - number;
       }
       static double der_f(double x) {
           return (double) n*pow(x, n-1);
       }
    };
    wrap::n = n;

    while( abs(x1-x0) < epsilon) {
        x0 = x1;
        x1 = x0 -wrap::f(x0)/wrap::der_f(x0); 
    }
    return x1;
}
```

Something like this.

Comment: This is good, but I am still having debugging issues. Now, the program can not run because I receive this message "Reference to local variable 'n' declared in enclosed function 'newton'"

Answer (score 1):

Move

```
   double f(double x) {
        return (double) pow(x, n) - number;
    }
    double der_f(double x) {
        return (double) n*pow(x, n-1);
    }
```

to outside of `double newton( int n, int number) {`

Comment: I am aware that I can solve that problem by moving the function outside. Can't this function be inside the newton function?

Comment: If you use C++11, you can use lambda functions for that (or boost::lambda without C++11, but then you have to include a library)

Comment: I see. Well, I am very use to javascript and I love how lenient it is compared to c++. I now know why I can not declare functions inside functions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you're declaring new functions inside of a function, which is not possible. Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cctype>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "helloworld.h"
#include <locale>

using namespace std;
double newton( int n, int number);
string lowercase (string word);


double f(double x) {
    return (double) pow(x, n) - number;
}

double der_f(double x) {
    return (double) n*pow(x, n-1);
}

int main() {
  int n;
  int number;
  cout << "This program can find the nth root of a number without actually solving the problem" <<endl;
  cout << "Tell me what the value of n is: ";
  cin >> n;
  cout << "What is the number that you want to get rooted";
  cin >> number;
  newton(n, number);
}

double newton( int n, int number) {
  const double epsilon = .0001;
  double x0;
  double x1 = number;
  // and here call the functions
  f();
  der_f();
  while( abs(x1-x0) < epsilon ) {
    x0 = x1;
    x1 = x0 -f(x0)/der_f(x0); 
  }
  return x1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is already pointed out, you have to get rid of local functions. Another way of doing it in C++11 is to use *[lambda-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11)*:

```
auto f = [=](double x) {
  return (double) pow(x, n) - number;
};
auto der_f = [=](double x) {
  return (double) n*pow(x, n-1);
};
```

All you need in this case is to replace `double func_name(double x)` with `auto func_name = [=](double x)`.

The `[=]` is a *[lambda-introducer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293603.aspx)*. By `=` you're telling that you want all of your local variables to be accessible in a lambda-function *by value*. This is the most appropriate way in your case since you only have variables of basic types and you don't want to modify them from your local functions.

The `auto` keyword tells a compiler to automatically deduce type of a variable for storing a function from the initialization clause. One can `std::function<double(double)>` instead of `auto` here.

Comment: It's not correct that the deduced type for a lambda will be `std::function`.