# C++'s most vexing parse again

Tags: c++, c++11, gotw

Taken directly from http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/09/gotw-1-solution/

While `widget w();` is clear for me, I have no idea how can the below code be a function declaration?

```
// same problem (gadget and doodad are types)
//
widget w( gadget(), doodad() );  // pitfall: not a variable declaration
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In a function declaration, arguments of type array decay into pointers to the first element, arguments of type function decay into a function pointer, so the signature would be:

```
widget w( gadget(*)(), doodad(*)() );
```

That is, a function that takes as the first argument a pointer to a function taking no arguments and returning `gadget`, that takes as second argument a pointer to a function taking no arguments and returning a `doodad` and that the function itself returns a `widget`

There are even more interesting or confusing cases, like:

```
// assume 'x' is a variable defined somewhere:
widget w(gadget(x));
```

How could *that* be interpreted as a function declaration? I mean, `x` is a variable, right? Well, when declaring a variable you can add extra parenthesis, so `gadget x;` and `gadget (x);` both declare the same variable `x`. The same applies to function arguments so the code above looks like a declaration of a function that takes a first argument named `x` of type `gadget` and returns a `widget`...

Comment: Mother of God. ಠ_ಠ

Comment: +1 first time knowing that  arguments of type function decay into a function pointer. thank you!

Comment: @Yanko: of course, that is why now you can use `widget w{gadget{}, doodad{}};` => this cannot be misconstrued as a function :)

Comment: @MatthieuM. For those of you lucky enough to use C++11 :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I am afraid I am lucky yet... at least, at work.

Comment: +1 for widget w(gadget(x)); That one is really strange.

Answer (score 1):

It's function that gets two functions, that returns `gadget` and `doodad` and either of them gets no arguments.

Example that compiles fine.

```
#include <iostream>
class widget{};
class gadget{};
class doodad{};
gadget a(){}
doodad b() {};
widget w( gadget(), doodad() ){
}
int main() {
    w(a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/YjZK9Y