# Overloading () operator in a class with default constructor

Tags: c++

I realize this isn't necessarily something you would want to do, but I ran into some code similar to this the other day. So, I want to look into the idea a bit more...

I have a class that has overloaded a constructor and a functor. This works as expected. However, when you call a class with the default constructor and then try to use the functor, it fails (because it can't figure out how to convert the class to an int, which isn't what I would want, anyhow.) What would be the correct way of doing this?

```
#include <cstdio>

class foo
{
public:
    foo(int a, int b);
    foo();
    int operator()();
private:
    int result;
};

foo::foo(int a, int b)
{
    printf("I am a foo(int, int). a: %d b: %d\n", a, b);
    result = a + b;
}

foo::foo()
{
    printf("I am a base foo!\n");
    result = -1;
}

int foo::operator()()
{
    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    int ret1 = -12345;
    int ret2 = -12345;

    foo myfoo(3, 8);
    foo otherfoo();

    ret1 = myfoo();
    ret2 = otherfoo(); //fails. Also, otherfoo()() fails.

    printf("foo: %d otherfoo: %d\n", ret1, ret2);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Surprisingly, the

```
foo otherfoo();
```

declares a function and not an object. See [C++ Gotchas (Gotcha #19: Function/Object Ambiguity)](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=L5ZbzVnpkXAC&pg=PA51) for a discussion.

To fix, change that line to

```
foo otherfoo;
```

or, in C++11, to

```
foo otherfoo{};
```

Comment: Or `foo otherfoo{};` in C++11

Comment: Thanks @BrianBi. I've added that to the answer.

Comment: NPE, that link is very very very susceptible to link rot. There is already a lot of good discussion on [C++'s most vexing parse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588750/cs-most-vexing-parse-again) right here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

There is an ambiguiuty between function declarations and object definitions. They have the same syntax. So it was decided to consider this syntax as a function declaration. Thus in this statement

```
foo otherfoo();
```

there is a function declaration that have return type foo and does not accept arguments.

To define an object of a class using the default constructor and at the same time zero-initialize its members you can use the following syntax

```
foo otherfoo {};
```