# How to disable implicit constructor conversion, while allowing copy-initialization

Tags: c++, c++11

Assuming we have something like:

```
class U {
  ...
}
```

and:

```
class T {
  T(const U&) { ... }
}
```

Now I can declare a variable like so:
`U foo;` then `T blah(foo);` or `T blah = foo`

Personally I prefer the later.

Now, should I change the T copy constructor to:

```
class T {
  explicit T(const U&) { ... }
}
```

I can only declare a variable like:
`T blah(foo);` `T blah = foo;` will give me a compilation error about the impossibility to convert U to T.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit explains that behaviour with:
"Specifies constructors and (since C++11) conversion operators that don't allow implicit conversions or **copy-initialization**."

Now, the folks I work for require that all our constructors are made explicit.
Being an old fart, I don't like changing my coding style too much and forget about T blah = ... style.

The question as such is this:
"Is there a way to make a constructor explicit while allowing copy-initialization syntax?"

There are very good reasons to make a constructor explicit, and most of the time, you **do** want to make it explicit.

Under those instances, I thought I could do something along the line of:

```
class T {
  template<typename = V>
  T(const V&) = delete;
  T(const U&) { ... }
}
```

Which would be a catch-all constructor forbidding all conversion but the one I actually want.

Was wondering if there was some trick I could use.

Thanks

Edit: corrected the typo as pointed by Matt McNabb answer. thanks

Answer (score 3):

`T blah = U();` gives the error because, as you correctly explain, copy-initialization calls for implicit conversion of `U` to `T`; but you have marked the constructor `explicit`. (Note: this is not a copy constructor)

Explicit conversion would look like `T blah = T(U());` and this should work with no errors.

`T blah(U());` is a function declaration (look up [most vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588750/cs-most-vexing-parse-again)).  You probably didn't actually try to use `blah` as if it were an object, in your test case, otherwise you would have noticed this problem.

---

Moving onto your question:

> Is there a way to make a constructor explicit while allowing copy-initialization syntax?

There is not, as explained by the exact text you quoted about `explicit`:

> Specifies constructors [...] that don't allow [...] copy-initialization.

You'll have to switch to direct or braced initialization. IMHO that's a good thing anyway, copy-initialization is cumbersome and only good for avoiding MVPs; but now that we can avoid MVPs using braced initialization, it's no longer necessary at all.

You could use either of the following, which work because in all cases a `T` is directly and explicitly initialized by the list element:

```
T blah{ U() };
T blah = T{ U() };  // redundant copy/move operation, probably elided
```

Note that `T blah = { U() };` cannot be used here because that form of initialization (known as *copy-list-initialization*) cannot use an explicit constructor.

Comment: `T blah = { U() };` does not mean `T blah = { T(U()) };`. Copy-list-initialization does not, even conceptually, construct a temporary `T`.

Comment: @T.C. OK, can you edit my last para to be correct (and fix any other terminology if required). I checked with compiler rather than standard, and it rejected `T blah = { U(); }` due to the constructor being explicit and so I assumed it was because a `T` had to be created

Comment: You're right... I wrote to fast trying to conceptualise the problem. My actual use would have been: U foo; T blah = foo;

Comment: @MattMcNabb OK, edited. The standard just outlaws explicit constructors directly in that case (i.e., if overload resolution selects one, the code is ill-formed).