# error C2601: "Name": local function definitions are illegal

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm new to C++ and learning about Inheritance and Polymorphism. We require to write an employee project that have 4 types of employee (BasePlusCommission, CommisisonEmployee, Salaried and TipWorker). My project has one main() class that I used switch method for each type of employee. I got stuck on TipWorker where we have to do Polymorphism. Here what I got so far.

```
int main()
{
void virtualViaPointer(const Employee * const);
    {
                cout << "Enter First Name: " << endl;
                cin >> firstName;
                cout << "Enter Last Name: " << endl;
                cin >> lastName;
                cout << "Enter SSN: " << endl;
                cin >> SSN;
                if (SSN.length() == 9)
                {
                    SSN = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "Please enter SSN again with 9 digits only:" << endl;
                    cin >> SSN;
                }
                cout << "Enter wages: " << endl;
                cin >> wage;
                cout << "Enter hours: " << endl;
                cin >> hours;
                cout << "Enter tips: " << endl;
                cin >> tips;

                TipWorker employee4(firstName, lastName, SSN, wage, hours, tips);
                employee4.print();
                cout << fixed << setprecision(2);

                vector < Employee * > employees(1);
                employees[0] = &employee4;

                cout << "Employee processed polymorphically via dynamic binding: \n\n";
                cout << "Virtual function calls made off base-class pointers:\n\n";
                for (const Employee *employeePtr : employees)
                    virtualViaPointer(employeePtr);
                void virtualViaPointer(const Employee * const baseClassPtr)
                {
                    baseClassPtr->print();
                    cout << "\nEarned $" << baseClassPtr->earnings() << "\n\n";
                }
                    break;
      }
}
```

When I run the project, I came up with this error:

> error C2601: "virtualViaPointer": local function definitions are
>   illegal

```
void virtualViaPointer(const Employee * const baseClassPtr)
                    {
                        baseClassPtr->print();
                        cout << "\nEarned $" << baseClassPtr->earnings() << "\n\n";
                    }
```

Can anyone please help me? Thank you so much!

Comment: it is quite self explanatory. You defined virtualViaPointer inside function main, and in C++ you can not have local functions(excluding lambdas, but they have different syntax)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ can we have functions inside functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324763/c-can-we-have-functions-inside-functions)

Comment: so how can I fix this error? Because I'm not really quite understand what you mean

Comment: Nevermind, I think I got it now. I fixed. But thank you for your ideas

Answer (score 3):

You may not define one function inside an other function. Any function definition shall be outside any other function definition.

Place the definition of `virtualViaPointer` outside the body of `main`.

Comment: I got that part now. It worked when I placed it outside my main(). But how can I increase the income 20%. Can you please help me on that?

Comment: @Phu Nguyen I do not know how you calculate the income but is not it enough to multiply it by 1.2?

Comment: LoL, I asked so many dumb questions. I actually solved it. I multiplied by 1.2 but used it in a wrong place. Thanks for your response too :)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a declaration of a function inside a function, but no definition(!) of that function. However, you can have a local struct/class or lambda in the function:

```
#include <iostream>
void f()
{
  void print(); // mostly useless - maybe a most vexing parse error
  struct Print {
    static void apply(const char* s) { std::cout << s << '\n'; }
  }
  Print::apply("Hello");
  auto lambda = [] (const char* s) { std::cout << s << '\n'; };
  lambda("World");
}
```

Note: A local struct does not require C++11 (Also, it may look nicer while debugging)