# Nesting int main() inside int main()

Tags: c++

I am trying to make the simplest of all games, but with a loop function.

I'm given the error "a function-definition is not allowed here before '{', as well as a whole list of [Error] expected '}' at end of input.

Am I not allowed to nest int main() within another? Is that my issue at all? How do I accomplish this code without the nesting?

My knowledge and experience extend no more than a few chapters in two books.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char again = 'y';
    while (again == 'y')


    int main()
        {

            srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time (0)));
            int secret = rand() % 100 +1;
            int tries = 0;
            int guess;
            cout << "\tGuess the random number\n\n";

            do 
                {
                    cout << "Enter a guess: ";
                    cin >> guess;
                    ++ tries;
                    if (guess > secret)
                        {
                            cout << "Too High!\n\n:";
                        }
                    else if (guess < secret)
                        {
                            cout << "Too Low!\n\n";
                        }
                    else 
                        {
                            cout << "\nThat's It! You go it in " << tries << " guesses!\n";
                        }
} while (guess != secret);
}

cout << "\n\tWould you like to play again? (y/n): ";
char again;
cin >> again;


}
```

Comment: you're not allowed to nest main with another main

Comment: *"Is that my issue at all?"* - yes. WTH are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Can you try to put a semicolon after the nested main like so? `int main();`. This should make it work and have it nested

Comment: If you can't bind `main` as the unique entry point of your program then you are Over the Bounding Main.

Comment: You are not allowed to define **any** function inside another function. There's nothing special about `main` here. What is it that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Yes, Thank you very much, it runs now. It doesn't display anything, but at least it runs

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb, comment worth an answer. I would personally upvote it.

Comment: `while (again == 'y') { ... }` is how you write a loop, with your current thinking the `do { ... } while` loops also needs `int main()`.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: But you could just as well remove the line entirely. It would make more sense.

Comment: @FredLarson i am unsure. you would lose the nested function.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: What? There are no nested functions in C++!

Comment: @FredLarson possibly it's called different in the Standard. Not necessarily "nested". Perhaps "contained" or something.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324763/c-can-we-have-functions-inside-functions

Comment: @FredLarson IMO that answer should be revised

Comment: @Johannes Schaub-litb no, it is correct. `int main();` inside a function is a declaration and not a definition. The only way you can define functions inside other functions is via lambdas.

Comment: @otomo, incorrect, it has been possible since the first C++ release to define functions inside other functions. See the linked question thread

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I only see a thread which elaborates that it is not possible unless you use lambdas.  Your solution with the added semicolon does exactly what I said--it _declares_ a function.  The function body is missing so it cannot be a definition.  There is a support for nested functions in GNU C but it is not standard compliant C++.

Comment: @tomo the linked question itaelf says (against the rules, since it was not posted as an answer) that it is possible without lambdas

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is nesting a main function inside of the existing main function. (This is not allowed.) In general, (With the exception of some stuff you can do with structs/lambdas which approximate that kind of functionality) you shouldn't nest functions inside of each-other. If you merely remove the function declaration, then your code should work fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char again = 'y';
    while (again == 'y')

        {

            srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time (0)));
            int secret = rand() % 100 +1;
            int tries = 0;
            int guess;
            cout << "\tGuess the random number\n\n";

            do
                {
                    cout << "Enter a guess: ";
                    cin >> guess;
                    ++ tries;
                    if (guess > secret)
                        {
                            cout << "Too High!\n\n:";
                        }
                    else if (guess < secret)
                        {
                            cout << "Too Low!\n\n";
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            cout << "\nThat's It! You go it in " << tries << " guesses!\n";
                        }
                } while (guess != secret);

            cout << "\n\tWould you like to play again? (y/n): ";
            cin >> again;
        }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you cannot nest `int main()` inside of `int main()` for a number of reasons. In general, you can't define one function inside of another (defining "locally"). However, even if you *can*, your desire to do so should be a massive red flag that your design is off.

> NOTE: As Nathan Oliver pointed out in the comments, you *can* forward-declare a function "locally" (within another function), but the actual implementation must be outside. Even doing this, you should usually second-guess your design at this point.

You need to be asking yourself what you're trying to do.

- Are you wanting to group code together under a function to call repeatedly? Then create a separate function (with a different name) *outside* of `main()`.
- Are you wanting to repeat code? If so, you need a loop or a recursive function structure.
- Are you wanting to split up some behavior into several functions, but hide all but one function involved? If so, look into **classes** (not necessarily objects - you can also have static classes.)

Those are just three of **many** possibilities, and deciding exactly what you want to do and how you want to do it is your responsibility alone to decide, as a programmer.

Brief recap: as far as C++ (and C) are concerned, **if you're trying to declare any function inside any other function, you are doing something seriously wrong in design.**

---

On a more technical note, you should also understand precisely what `int main()` is. It is a special function that is the **entry point** for your program. No C or C++ program can run without an `int main()`.

You have to have a single instance of this function in `main.cpp` in order for your program to work. If you have more than one `int main()`, the computer cannot likely will not be able to find the entry point.

Besides that, having more than one function called `main()` *anywhere* in your code is a great way to confuse yourself and others.

In short, **you should only have one `int main()` per program, no exceptions.**

Comment: local function definitions are illegal period, It is not just limited to `main()`.

Comment: Also note that declaring a function locally is totally okay: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/76f71f801cf41043

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to get at that.

Comment: Updated to that effect. Also, your link isn't working for me, @NathanOliver.

Comment: Interesting that the link is not working.  try this one: https://ideone.com/AOHK3w

Comment: @NathanOliver Ahh! I see what you mean now - it can be forward declared, but the implementation cannot be placed there.

Comment: Yes.  You can locally declare but not local define a function.