# Check multiple bits in bitset

Tags: c++, bit

I got the following code:

```
static int P, m, p, M;
static std::bitset<99> B;

p = B[m] & B[m + 5] & B[m + 6] & B[m + 11];

m -= d * (l > 0) * 11 + !d * (c % 5 > 0);

p += m ^ M ? B[m] & B[m + 5] & B[m + 6] & B[m + 11] : 0;
```

I know it's hard to read, but here's a TL;DR for it: I check multiple bits (all are related to `m`) in a bitset, then I change the value of variable `m` and I check again (other bits).

Is there a way i can access those bits in less code, or to template the check (cuz are the same formulas for bits)?

```
B[m] & B[m + 5] & B[m + 6] & B[m + 11]
```

Thank you :D.

Comment: would be easier to read if you would declare the variables

Comment: static int P, m, p, M;
 static bitset<99> B;

Comment: Interestingly enough, your bitset fits into one SSE register, which would allow to precompute the `B[m]&B[m+5]&...` extremely fast for all `m` values at the same time

Comment: Idk what you talking about, but i don't want to change the structure(bitset) into something else that would ruine the whole code. Could you link me something?

Comment: @aleeN1 I don't think you have to change anything, chances are the compiler will make use of it. Just notice that `bitset<99>` is very lightweight so it's perfectly okay to copy it around

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using a function to precompute a helper bitset for that:

```
bitset<99> prepare_bitset(const bitset<99>& B)
{
   return B & (B<<5) & (B<<6) & (B<<11);
}
```

Then you can just use it like this:

```
auto HB = prepare_bitset(B);
p = HB[m];
m -= d * (l > 0) * 11 + !d * (c % 5 > 0);
p += m ^ M ? HB[m] : 0;
```

**UPD**: Another option is to just define `HB` in place:

```
auto HB = B & (B<<5) & (B<<6) & (B<<11);
p = HB[m];
m -= d * (l > 0) * 11 + !d * (c % 5 > 0);
p += m ^ M ? HB[m] : 0;
```

Comment: can i do that inside the function? I'm talking about prepare_bitset function, can i write in inside another function?

Comment: I'll try it out. I thought lambdas can only be used as parameters for functions.

Answer (score 3):

Make a function that takes B and m.

So `p = yourFunc(B, m)` and `p += m ^M ? yourFunc(B, m) : 0`

The function is something like:

```
TYPEOFP yourFunc(TYPEOFB b, TYPEOFM m) {
    return b[m] & b[m + 5] & b[m + 6] & b[m + 11];
}
```

I don't know your types, so you need to fill it in.

I wouldn't recommend a macro, but if you want that it's

```
#define yourMACRO(b, m) ((b)[(m)] & (b)[(m) + 5] & (b)[(m) + 6] & (b)[(m) + 11])
```

All of those extra parens are to protect you if you ever pass in an expression for b or m. The macro will fail if you pass in something with side-effects (like ++m).

EDIT: From your comments, you said you can't write outside the function.

It's unorthodox, but you can do the `#define` in the function and `#undef` it at the end of the function.

Depending on the version of C++ you have, you might have lambdas, which let you make function expressions.

If you are desperate, you can define an inner class or struct with a static function: [C++ can we have functions inside functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324763/c-can-we-have-functions-inside-functions)

Comment: The code it's from a function. I can't write anything outside of the function. I forgot to specify this. Sorry.

Comment: What version of C++?

Comment: Latest one. 14 i think it is

Comment: Use a lambda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11

Comment: I thought about it, but i can't figure out how to do it exactly, cuz it's a complex one..