# Editing an instance of a class that has not yet been defined

Tags: c++, function, class

Is it possible to edit an object that has not yet been defined in a function? For example, if I had a class in one file that adds one to a number:

```
class MyClass
{
    private:
       int i;

    public:
        MyClass()
        {
            i = 0;
        }

        int addOne()
        {
            i += 1;
            return i;
        }
};
```

And in another file, the class is imported. When the `add` function is called it calls the `addOne` function from the class:

```
#include "MyClass.h"

void add()
{
    a.addOne();
}

int main()
{
    MyClass a;
    add();

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this it returns the error

> error: ‘a’ was not declared in this scope

Is there any way for this to work?

Sites I read but didn't help solve my problem:

- http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/unices/21527/
- [When can I use a forward declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration
- [Can we have functions inside functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324763/can-we-have-functions-inside-functions)

Comment: Why would you want / expect it to work?

Comment: You have to pass `a` to `add()` e.g. `void add(MyClass &a) { a.addOne(); }` and call it in `main()` with `add(a);`.

Comment: do you understand what "declared in this scope" means? That's a pretty important pre-requisite to programming

Comment: do you know what `#include` is used for?

Comment: did you search for your error message and try to understand it?

Comment: Would the down-votes care to explain please? I find that a reasonable and carefully crafted question.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann as I said in my comment - lack of research effort

Comment: @UKMonkey To me the question is: "Is there an alternative for X?" (I tried X, it gave me an error.) OP is interested in the alternative not the error. The question is not how can I resolve this error but to understand first principles, IMHO. In fact that OP tried to first work it out herself is noble, again IMHO.

Comment: @UKMonkey I actually did a lot of research but I couldn't find an answer that I could understand or would work for me (I'm very new to C++). I tried looking into forward referencing as I thought that could solve my problem but nothing helped.

Comment: @T.Green Then it's important you state in your question what you found  and tried; else how do we know which part you didn't understand?

Comment: You may want to look at [scope](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope)

Comment: I would also suggest looking up function arguments and references.  If you're lacking a resource that can tell you what these are (for example you're not understanding the websites) then I'd suggest looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) page to help you with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is something like this :

```
void add( MyClass & a)
{
    int num = a.addOne();
}

int main()
{
    MyClass newObj;
    // passing the new object to add
    add(newObj);

    return 0;
}
```

1. The method **add()** has no idea about the "a" which you were trying to use and was therefore giving you an error.
2. The method **addOne()** has a return type of an int, so it is expected that when you use a method that returns a value, then you do something with it.