# error: expected ‘}’ at end of input — when all brackets are closed

Tags: c++

This program I wrote is supposed to print some numbers:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int hitung(int A[], int n) 
    {
        int jumlah = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        {
            jumlah = jumlah + A[i];
            if (i % 2 == 1) 
            {
                cout << A[i];
            }
        }
        return jumlah;
    }
}
```

However, when I try to compile it I get these error messages:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:6:5: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
     {
     ^
main.cpp:18:1: error: expected '}' at end of input
 }
 ^
```

**While the first error is understandable since function definition can't be in other function**, I don't understand the 2nd error since all my brackets are closed.

Why is the compiler producing the second error?

Comment: You can't define a function inside another function.

Comment: @Bathsheba There is?  I count 4 { and 4 }.  Do note the if statement has a open curly brace in there.

Comment: Your (lack of) formatting makes it hard to read your code and thus more likely you'll make this kind of mistake

Comment: My error is `error: a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘{’ token`.

Comment: It remains a low-quality question a duplicate of many, one without any textual explanation and should remain closed

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels If it's a duplicate, it should be flagged with the duplicate so that others who find this question will be able to find the duplicate.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: If it was for a missing brace, it **was** a typo. But this is not even valid C++ code.

Comment: A tip on code formatting: to format your code you should select all of it then hit ctrl + K.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324763/can-we-have-functions-inside-functions

Comment: @Olaf Sure, if it was a typo, it would be a typo. Agreed. And of course it's not valid code, the question is about a compilation error.

Comment: so my code is incomplete?

Comment: My errors are `expected a ';'` and `local function definitions are illegal`

Comment: @MUtiaraYustika Your question was answered by the very first comment. Move `hitung` outside of `main`.

Comment: You all missed the point. The question is not on the first error, it is about the second one.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: No, the question is about a grammar/semantics error. The syntax is correct. Digging deeper: the question is about not having understood the basics of the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined the function `hitung` into `main()`. You cannot do that. What you can do however is this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int hitung(int A[], int n) 
{
    int jumlah = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        jumlah = jumlah + A[i];
        if (i % 2 == 1) 
        {
            cout << A[i];
        }
    }
    return jumlah;
}

int main()
{
   int a[] = {1, 2, 3};
   cout << hitung(a, 3) << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you could declare your function before `main()`, and define it afterwards.