# Fill in the blanks

Tags: c++

Constructor ________ to allow different approaches of object construction.

1. Cannot overload
2. Can be overload
3. Can be called
4. Can be nested

Comment: None of the above. Answer is: Can be overload**ed**. :)

Comment: @P.W Give him a break. At least the question doesn't look like copy pasted from elsewhere but typed by himself.

Comment: @josephting: Not the D-Voter

Comment: StackOverflow is not a homework service. Do some research, read your textbooks, and answer your own tests.

Comment: @josephting hey this question was from my OOP manual thats why I ask it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/function-overloading-c/), overloading is defined to be "a feature in C++ where two or more functions can have the same name but different parameters." Constructor can be overloaded by allowing for same names and different parameters. For example, you can refer to [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/constructor-overloading-c/). Nesting functions is not supported by C++. Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324763/can-we-have-functions-inside-functions). Calling a constructor does nothing related to allowing different approaches of object construction.

Comment: Sorry I didn't add anything new. I just did the research online and copy and paste examples from others. :)