# Is there a technical reason for not allowing nested function definitions?

Tags: c++, function

Why C++ does not allow something like:

```
int foo(int x) {
    void bar(int x) { return x*x;}
    return bar(x);
}
```

Disclaimer: I am not asking for the rationale for disallowing it. We can define classes inside functions, in particular functors, and since C++11 lambdas, so actually I do not see the need for it.

However, I wonder if there is some technical limitation/problem that would prevent to allow it. Would it create ambiguities syntax-wise? Other problems that I dont see? Or is the answer perhaps simply: It is not allowed because there is no need for it?

Comment: That syntax comes from K&R C, do you want to ask them?

Comment: it is possible with gcc gnuC

Comment: @OznOg oh that actually answers my question ;)

Comment: @OznOg as I understand, not in standard c, but gnu c. Anyhow, there is no technical limitation

Comment: @Mär the duplicate kind of prooves that there is no technical limitation. The q you propose as dupe is more about defining something "function-like" or callable, while I specifically ask for functions. Anyhow I'll add it to the list

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Thanks for elaboration.

Comment: @Mär no idea waht is going on here. I wanted to add your link to the list of duplciates, but somehow the question has been reopened meanwhile and now I cannot flag as dupe again...

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Let me close it and you can add it.

Comment: @NathanOliver do you know if I can find out who reopenend the question? Not that it really matters, just curious.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 You can see that in the timeline: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58510922/timeline

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4327317/10809870

Comment: @NathanOliver sorry for bothering you, how do I find the timeline (unless you give me the link ;) ?

Comment: It's `stackoverflow.com/posts/post_id/timeline` where you can get `post_id` from the URL (it's the number between questions and the question title in the URL).  This also works for answers.  You just need to click the share button and the post id will be the first number after `a/` in the URL.

Comment: @NathanOliver ah ok, thanks again

Comment: No problem.  It's a nice tool to have.  Do note that SO is no longer maintaining it and it could disappear at any time.

Comment: The technical reason is stated in Jerry Coffin's answer in the first duplicate. Lambas aren't recursive so don't have this problem, but then they aren't fully equivalent to nested functions for the same reason.