# Why does visual studio say I need a semicolon after declaring this function?

Tags: visual-c++

```
Void function(int x) {
    x = 1;
}
```

Visual studio shows an error that I need a semicolon here: (int x) ^ {
I have never seen a semicolon in this place for a function though.  What is going on here?

Comment: did you write "void" or "Void" in your code?

Comment: Are you trying to define a function outside of a class?  Because a semi-colon where you indicate would imply a function forward definition.

Comment: void with lowercase v @jcoder

Comment: Ah, thanks for mentioning that @Peter M.  I attempted to declare the function inside int main().

Comment: should have known it was a simple mistake like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question here for those who need help with the same issue in the future.

C++ doesn't support declaring/defining normal functions within other functions, such as main(). The only way to do this would be inline functions (lambdas). More information about nested functions can be found here: [Can we have functions inside functions in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324763/can-we-have-functions-inside-functions-in-c)